# Elasticsearch - How can I include specific facet values in an aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following field and values for my documents:

`publication_year`: 2000, 2001, 2002, ..., 2020

I'd like to aggregate by `publication_year`, return the top 5 buckets, but also add specific buckets to the result (selected by the user), even if they are not among the top 5 buckets.

Desired result:

```
2001 (100)
2002 (88)
2003 (5) - selected
2007 (77)
2014 (15)
```

How can I include one or more particular facet values among the returned buckets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an elegant way to do it within one aggregation so I'd suggest the following:

1. Query for books that match the year filter
2. Aggregate globally w/o applying the filter but exclude the "selected" years
3. Aggregate the selected years separately (since their presence in the top 5 buckets from above cannot be guaranteed)
4. Combine the resulting buckets wherever you get the ES response

```
GET books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "publication_year": [ 2003 ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_non_selected_years": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "by_year": {
          "terms": {
            "exclude": [ 2003 ],
            "field": "publication_year",
            "size": 5,
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "selected_years": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "publication_year"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically I need to add an extra aggregation for each selected facet value. And probably the best way to do this would be to add a filter inside that aggregation. Ok, I'll have to think this through, because I have a lot of facets, not just one as in this example. I was expecting a straight forward solution and this complicates matters a bit.

Comment: I intentionally used a `terms` query which is an OR of multiple values. Same w/ the `excludes` param -- it accepts an array too! You could use `filter` aggs too but as soon as you have any non-empty top-level query, your aggs will be limited to the docs that fulfil that particular query -- not *all* of them as was requested in your question.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarifications. I actually don't use a top-level query, but `post_filter`, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Oh ok. No prob! Hey, my ES handbook is coming out soon and [I'd like to hear your input](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) before it does.